# StaggeredGridLayoutManager without ItemDecoration

Tags: android

StaggeredGridLayoutManager without ItemDecoration needs onScroll to arrange the items in matrix/Grid format. Is there a way to avoid ItemDecoration because I don't want decorator between items.

```
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(3,StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)) 
//Without addItemDecoration - it requires a scroll to occupy all the columns
recycler.addItemDecoration(new CustomInsetsDecoration(context));
```

without item decoration --

```
A
B
C
D
E
F
```

with item decoration (with min 1px/dp apart)

```
A B C
D E F
```

What I want:

```
ABC
DEF
```

A,B,C,D,E,F are all are ImageViews (of different sizes)

My item layout - a very simple - relativelayout and an Imageview:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_browse_cover"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Any input is appreciated. 
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what does your layout look like for the items

Comment: Updated my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following `MarginDecorator` class with a 0 margin

```
public class MarginDecorator extends RecyclerView.ItemDecoration {

    private int margin;

    public MarginDecorator(int margin) {
        this.margin = margin;
    }

    @Override
    public void getItemOffsets(Rect outRect, View view, RecyclerView parent, RecyclerView.State state) {
        outRect.top = margin;
        outRect.bottom = margin;
        outRect.left = margin;
        outRect.right = margin;
    }
}
```

Also try using the [`setGapStrategy()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/StaggeredGridLayoutManager.html#setGapStrategy(int))

Comment: It results no margin. Thanks. But, the fundamental problem is, all the items fall in a line until onScroll manually.

Comment: @vasanth didn't get you there, could you explain it again :)

Comment: I will try - I use this recycler.setLayoutManager(new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(6, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL)) but when I use the margin decorator with 0dp - images gets rendered one below the other in the first column and rest of the columns remain unoccupied until there is a small scroll manually. Hope it's clear now. Thanks.